# multiple log_opts for docker logging

Tags: docker, docker-compose

My `docker-compose` file looks like this. It works great. My logs show up on my syslog server.   The problem is that I cannot view them locally in `/var/log/messages`. Any way I can do both?

```
mydocker:
  image: mydocker
  log_driver: syslog
  log_opt:
    syslog-address: "<url-goes-here>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the answer is [no](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/17910). As mentioned in the link you could syslog/journald to the host and further process the logs from there. Creating your own little log container shouldn't be too hard either.